# Cast from type parametrized by const template argument to non-const template argument

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have a class with variadic template parameters:

```
template<typename... Args>
class something {
public:
  something(Args&&... args); // omitted for brevity
}
```

I have a function that accepts a list of arguments and returns an object of this class:

```
template<typename... Args>
auto make_something(Args&&... args) {
    return something<Args...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

If I call it like so:

```
something<int, std::string> s = make_something<int, std::string>(1, "");
```

it compiles and works fine.

but if I try to pass a const argument, I get compile errors:

```
const std::string t = "";
something<int, std::string> s1 = make_something(1, t); // no viable conversion from something<... const basic_string<char>> to something<... std::string>
```

How can I successfully pass const and then, idk, cast the result to the requested type, parametrized by a non-const type?

I suspect it has something to do with the type of the object I'm returning but I don't actually know what to replace `auto` with in this case.

Comment: Notice that your constructor `something(Args&&...);` doesn't use forwarding references, as types are fixed by the class.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean. Do you suggest I parametrize the constructor from the arguments with template parameters A1 and Args1...? Or do you mean that I'm not calling `std::forward` to pass the arguments -- because I am, only I omitted the member initializer list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options, depending on if you really want to have `something<int, const std::string &>` be a type that `make_something(1, t)` returns.

If that is the case, you can have a converting constructor

```
template<typename... Args>
class something {
public:
  something(Args&&... args); // omitted for brevity
  template<typename... OtherArgs> 
  something(something<OtherArgs...>); // convert each OtherArgs into Args
}
```

In the alternative, where you want `make_something(1, t)` to result in `something<int, std::string>`

```
template<typename... Args>
class something {
public:
  template<typename... OtherArgs> 
  something(OtherArgs&&...); // use each OtherArgs for Args
}

template <typename... Args>
auto make_something(Args&&... args)
{
    return something<std::decay_t<Args>...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: thanks! the second option is what I need. However, I'm still having trouble getting it to work and I suspect the constructor is at fault (as pointed out, I guess, in the comments to the original question). Would you be so kind as to show what the constructor from args should look like here? Because I've been simply forwarding them but I guess that's... not enough? Should the constructor also have its own template parameters?

Comment: @wouldnotliketo it's because your constructor is defined for those exact types, rather than accepting anything that decays into those types

Answer (score 2):

You might do (if relevant):

```
template <typename... Args>
auto make_something(Args&&... args)
{
    return something<std::decay_t<Args>...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

So you got `something<int, std::string>` instead of `something<int, const std::string&>`